# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon after failed pull

Tags: docker, jupyter, systemd

When I try to pull a certain docker image, my pull fails, and then prevents me from connecting to the docker deamon again until I reboot my laptop. The Image in question is an official Jupyter images which works fine on my other machine. Restarting the Deamon does not help, but rebooting my laptop does.

I tried to `docker system prune -a` already, that's why there are no images on my laptop anymore. Does somebody have an idea how to fix this problem?

I think the problem might be connected to one of the images not finishing it's extraction.

**EDIT**

I have the same problem with a alpine image. see below

```sh
me@mylaptop $ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE

me@mylaptop $ docker pull jupyter/datascience-notebook
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from jupyter/datascience-notebook
e6ca3592b144: Extracting [==================================================>]  28.56MB/28.56MB
534a5505201d: Download complete 
990916bd23bb: Download complete 
979cd14ae800: Download complete 
5e8b9f8fa9e0: Download complete 
6f224ed88dc4: Download complete 
6ee9ec4a62a8: Download complete 
7a1ae22ba760: Download complete 
a1602338a8d7: Download complete 
fce5135a7ea1: Download complete 
e62a1c9017ef: Download complete 
a5049ad1c512: Download complete 
ec06c1612b0a: Download complete 
acceda87b341: Download complete 
939052532b6f: Download complete 
d2dee4cc07fe: Download complete 
4fe5e9dd4fad: Download complete 
8fd08517e0c6: Download complete 
7105a3ca8c38: Download complete 
66c0798f609e: Download complete 
94f3fc35ed38: Download complete 
aa68263474a3: Download complete 
6e7d1433394b: Download complete 
f5902e69d9b7: Download complete 
490bb991b4de: Download complete 
fab6e92b04fa: Download complete 
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error cleaning up after pivot: remove /.pivot_root297865553: device or resource busy

me@mylaptop $ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

```sh
me@mylaptop $ sudo systemctl start docker

me@mylaptop $ systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-09-30 08:11:12 CEST; 15min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 908 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 10
     Memory: 140.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─908 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

sep 30 08:11:11 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:11.992016198+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
sep 30 08:11:11 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:11.992433459+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
sep 30 08:11:12 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:12.227615723+02:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can b>
sep 30 08:11:12 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:12.296603004+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
sep 30 08:11:12 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:12.486944893+02:00" level=warning msg="Not using native diff for overlay2, this may cause degraded performance for building images: >
sep 30 08:11:12 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:12.487273874+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=48a66213fe graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.12-ce
sep 30 08:11:12 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:12.491959213+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
sep 30 08:11:12 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:12.530816090+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
sep 30 08:11:12 mylaptop systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
sep 30 08:23:36 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:23:36.941202710+02:00" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar fi>

me@mylaptop $ docker images
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

```
me@mylaptop $ docker pull alpine:3.12.0
3.12.0: Pulling from library/alpine
df20fa9351a1: Extracting [==================================================>]  2.798MB/2.798MB
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error cleaning up after pivot: remove /.pivot_root517304538: device or resource busy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. The problem is that my kernel was/became to old.

The warning below by systemctl brought made me find this post on [forums.docker.com](https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-to-start-docker/93765)

```
me@mylaptop $ systemctl status docker
...
sep 30 08:11:11 mylaptop dockerd[908]: time="2020-09-30T08:11:11.992016198+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
...
```

I'm running Manjaro so I upgrade my kernel with this command:

```
sudo mhwd-kernel -i linux54
```

After which docker worked again.